# Windows DNS server: Own IP in the DNS settings?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I have following network devices:

- 10.0.22.1 = Router
- 10.0.22.10 = Windows Server, acts as AD, DNS and DHCP

Question:

In the Windows Ethernet settings of the server, I have currently entered:

```
IP-Address:    10.0.22.10
Subnet mask:   255.255.255.0 [sic]
Gateway:       10.0.22.1

DNS Server:    10.0.22.10
               10.0.22.1
```

This works so far, but I wonder if the DNS settings are correct. Is it OK to enter the server's own IP address, or am I supposed to enter the "upstream" DNS servers (i.e. the router) like so?:

```
DNS Server:    10.0.22.1
               8.8.8.8 (Google Backup in case something goes wrong at ISP level)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it configured to itself and *only* to itself. The DNS server itself does recursive lookups back against the root name servers. You should not be configuring any public DNS servers (`8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1` or anything like that) unless you have an explicit reason to.

Comment: Thank you very much for that information!